# How to prevent sort action in container?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I prevent sort action in jQuery UI for `<h1>Title</h1>`?

```
<div data-user-type="mix" class="col-xs-3">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div data-userId="1" class="user">
        <h2>John</h2>
    </div>
    <div data-userId="2" class="user">
        <h2>Bill</h2>
    </div>
    <div data-userId="3" class="user">
        <h2>Max</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my try

```
$(function() {
    $('div[data-user-type="mix"]').sortable({
        revert: true
    });
    $('h1').disableSelection();
});
```

Now I can sort all user and `title`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`disableSelection()` will only disable it from being draggable as other items can change it's position. You need to exclude the items from the selector of sortable.

```
$('div[data-user-type="mix"]').sortable({
    revert: true,
    items: ':not(h1)'
});
```

---

To connect two lists:

```
<div id="list1" class="connect">

</div>

<div id="list2" class="connect">

</div>
```

Connects using the same class name:

```
$('#list1, #list2').sortable({
       connectWith: 'connect'
});
```

It's all in the docs: [Connect Lists](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists)

Comment: Ok. And if I would have another `<div data-user-type="admins" class="col-xs-3">` with other users than how can I drag one user from one group <div> to another?

Comment: +1.  It is cleaner, however, to specify what the items are, not what they aren't.  e.g. `items: '.class'` in this case.  Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/eyh6m14m/

Comment: I agree. Thought the `:not` helps visualise what's going on with exclusions.

Comment: @bowheart If I drag all users from one group to another I can't drag them back. I mean If in `ADMIN` group there are no users (they are all in `MIX` group) in that case I cannot to drag any users back to Admin group.

Comment: You can. It's just that the div is really small without elements. It needs a `min-height` so you can easily drag back in.